# Is this normal QQ plot light or heavy tailed? First QQ plot I'm trying to analyse on my own

Tags: qq-plot

I think if it wasn't for the outliers on the tails, I'd be sure this normal QQ plot is light tailed but I'm not sure.

I'm aware I can use formal tests to find out, but I was told statisticians like to analyse plots without having to resort to tests if possible, and I'd like to develop the same type of intuition.

[image]

Edit: I applied the shapiro test, and there is evidence against normality. The p value was ~0.04. How does the plot show this?